# How do I put the JMenuBar on top in mac and change the background of a JButton

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenubar

I am building a Mac desktop application in java. I want to change the background of a JButton and also I want to make my JMenuBar be in the top.

To put my JMenuBar on the top I added this code:

```
  System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
  System.setProperty(
      "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Stack");
```

And it worked!

And to change the backgroud color I used this:

```
    JButton b = new JButton("press me!");

    b.setBackground(Color.blue);

    b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    b.setOpaque(true);
    b.setBorderPainted(true);
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                .getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

And it also worked!

The problem was that when I changed the color the JMenuBar was not in the top. After a little debugging I know that changing the LookAndFeel is the responsable.

The complete code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        System.setProperty(
          "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Stack");

        JButton b = new JButton("press me!");           
        b.setBackground(Color.blue);    
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setBorderPainted(true);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                    .getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }   
        JFrame f = new JFrame();            
        f.add(b);           
        JMenuBar m = new JMenuBar();            
        m.add(new JMenu("item"));   
        f.setJMenuBar(m);
        f.setVisible(true);         
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So this code change the color of the button but the JMenuBar is not in the top. If you comment the lines in the try it will not change the color but it will put the JMenuBar on the top.

Any help??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `setLookAndFeel` normally also belongs at the start of the main - before the creation of any GUI.

Comment: So, you're asking that the MacOS place your menu bar within system menu bar, BUT, you're trying to use a cross platform look and feel...and you don't see a conflict there?

Comment: @MadProgrammer To be honest I have no idea what a cross platform look and feel is (dont even know what look and feel is), I just googled how to change the background of a JButton and that was what I founded. I would really appreciate if you would help me sort these out.

Comment: You want to use the System look and feel, the cross platform look and feel will want tot use metal (:P), you can get the button to work under Mac OS by using  and pass it false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the line

```
b.setUI(new MetalButtonUI());
```

and deleting the try catch.

It ended up looking like these:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name",
                "Stack");
        JButton b = new JButton("press me!");

        b.setBackground(Color.blue);

        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setBorderPainted(true);
        b.setUI(new MetalButtonUI());


        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.add(b);



        f.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        JMenuBar m = new JMenuBar();

        m.add(new JMenu("item"));



        f.setJMenuBar(m);
        f.setVisible(true);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a JMenu and a JMenuItem. This way you can multiple 'menu items' to a menu:

```
....

menubar = new JMenuBar();

menu1 = new JMenu();

menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("item 1");

// add menu item to menu
menu1.add(menuItem1);

// add menu to menubar
menubar.add(menu1);

....
```